# getRecord lightning/uiRecordApi for Field RecordTypeId DeveloperName not in response

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, ui-record-api

I'm trying to know if there is a way to fetch a record's -> recordTypeId -> DeveloperName without making a apex call from uiRecordApi adapter.

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { LightningElement, wire, api} from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

import CASE_RECORDTYPE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Case.RecordTypeId";

export default class someclass extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@api recordId;
@wire(getRecord,{recordId: '$recordId', fields:[CASE_RECORDTYPE_FIELD ]})
    getCaseRecord({data,error}){
        if(data){
            console.log('Record data --> '+JSON.stringify(data));
        }else if(error){
            //should Never Reach Here!
            console.error('ERROR => ', JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }
}

console:
Record data --> 
{
    "apiName": "Case",
    "childRelationships": {},
    "fields": {
        "RecordTypeId": {
            "displayValue": null,
            "value": "000000000000000000"
        }
    },
    "id": "000000000000000000",
    "lastModifiedById": "000000000000000000",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2021-08-11T14:42:49.000Z",
    "recordTypeId": "000000000000000000",
    "recordTypeInfo": {
        "available": true,
        "defaultRecordTypeMapping": false,
        "master": false,
        "name": "Case Sample", //**no developername :(**
        "recordTypeId": "000000000000000000"
    },
    "systemModstamp": "2021-08-11T14:42:49.000Z"
}
```

recordTypeInfo does not contains developername for record type it has only record type name.

Apart from doing apex call, Is there a way to fetch the RecordTypeId DeveloperName of current record we are on ?

Please do let me know in case there is an idea already or if it's in roadmap. I couldn't find any though!

Comment: try `import CASE_RECORDTYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.RecordType.DeveloperName';`

Comment: @Damecek Thank you :)

it worked 
this.data.fields.RecordType.value.fields.DeveloperName.value

Comment: @Damecek if you can post same in answer I will mark it as solution and close this one thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the RecordType you can go even further for the developer name, like so.

```
import CASE_RECORDTYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.RecordType.DeveloperName';
```